# Android & LuaJ 3.0 binding

Tags: java, android, lua, luaj

I am writing Android app using LuaJ 3.0. How can I bind my Java object to specific LuaClosure(for whole script)?

Lua code:

```
local  = state or nil
state.foo("some string")
```

Java code:

```
Prototype prototype;

    try{

        InputStream stream = mContext.getResources().getAssets().open(LUA_ASSETS_DIRECTORY + "test.lua");
        prototype = LuaC.compile(stream, "script");

    } catch (IOException e) {

        return false;
    }

    LuaClosure closure = new LuaClosure(prototype, mLuaGlobals);
    // binding code
    closure.call();
```

I know that in LuaJ 2.0(but not in 3.0) there was LuaValue.setenv, and also I know about creating libs and binding them to Globals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From LuaJ 3.0, the ability to modify closures are removed from the API.
If you just want to bind your Java objects to specific Lua environment, you can create multiple [Globals](http://luaj.sourceforge.net/api/3.0/org/luaj/vm2/Globals.html). You can then bind your Java objects to specific Globals, and create a closure from each of them:

```
Globals mLuaGlobals1 = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
Globals mLuaGlobals2 = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
Globals mLuaGlobals3 = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();

// binding code
mLuaGlobals1.rawset("state", CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(yourJavaObject));
mLuaGlobals2.rawset("state", CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(anotherJavaObject));
// We don't expose anything to mLuaGlobals3 in this example

// Create closures
// We use exact same prototype (script code) for each of them
LuaClosure closure1 = new LuaClosure(prototype, mLuaGlobals1);
LuaClosure closure2 = new LuaClosure(prototype, mLuaGlobals2);
LuaClosure closure3 = new LuaClosure(prototype, mLuaGlobals3);

closure1.call(); // yourJavaObject is exposed through "state" variable
closure2.call(); // anotherJavaObject is exposed through "state" variable
closure3.call(); // "state" variable is absent
```

Yes it's a silly solution, so if you really need the control of LuaClosure, downgrading to LuaJ 2.0.3 is the best option.

Comment: Thank you, I already downgrated by project to LuaJ 2. And yes - it is the best option.